# SD Card installed and still saying insuffisient storage

Tags: sd-card

trying to update apps and it tells me i have insufficient storage. We bought a 64 SD Card and tried again and it's still saying no storage.  Does this SD card not work for apps??

Comment: The answer to this question varies a lot based on your Android version and device, in some cases you must manually move apps and data there, in others you must adopt the card as internal storage. Please update your question to include your make, model, and Android version.

Comment: Have you gone into **Settings** then **Apps** and then clicked on the Apps you want on the SD card and moved them to the SD card? Some Apps can't be moved.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to place apps on sd card you should use apps2sd or link2sd app. Moving apps to sd car from app manager in settings doesn't actually move apps it moves just some files of them.
If your phone is running android marhsmallow (6.0) than you can 'adopt' an sd card so you can really move apps to sd card but beware if you have some slower sd card you will most likely have performance issues for obvious reasons.
Also did you tried clearing per app cache, that can free-up some memory.

Answer (score 0):

Download a Trashhandler like Clean Master lite and let it run, then you should save a lot of Storage space also you can move Files like photos and Downloads to your SD card